# output shell output from custom file via shell_exec in php

Tags: php, shell

I would like to display the output of a shell script like it is shown in PuTTy or gnome-terminal via a php-script. I tried using shell_exec by invoking it:

`$output = shell_exec('echo "return value: ";foo=$(nameOfFileToExecute); echo $foo');`

In which way can I get the return string of the script which is stored on the webserver?

Comment: Did you try `echo $output`, or if you're expecting more than one line output try `passthru` instead of `shell_exec`

Comment: I do output echo in my phpfile. It looks like nameOfFileToExecute won't be executed (and therefore no output is stored in foo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
    <?php 
         exec($your_shell_command_as_string, $arrayOfReturnedData);

        // NOW YOU CAN ACCESS ALL THE VALUES RETURNED BY THE SHELL COMMANDS VIA THE ARRAY.
        var_dump($arrayOfReturnedData); // DUMPS THE RESULTS OF THE SHELL COMMAND...
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: ok. Output is array(0) { }. Maybe a problem with the working directory of the script because it is located on a vhost?

Comment: Exactly... it should return an array with Data/Content  if there is anything.... ***perhaps, you may need to change your directory and try again...***

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the `nameOfFileToExecute`, so try using the full path `/path/to/executable/nameOfFileToExecute`

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the full path to file

and use this 2>&1 and know the error

try something like this

```
$comando = "sh pathTofile/location/ftpgesdoc.sh";

if(exec("$comando  2>&1", $output, $return_var))
{
   print_r($output);
   echo "<br>";
   print_r($return_var);

  }
```